# IPP Find All Accounts - Best Practice

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to pull all accounts for a QuickBooks Online account. My user has over 350 accounts to pull. Is there a way to pull them all at once? If not, is there a way to determine how many records there are to pull, then pull them in a group? Here is my code:

```
//pull a list of all accounts. I can only pull 100 at a time, so I need to keep enumerating until I hit 0
        Account acct = new Account();
        _accounts = new List<Account>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var aList = dataServices.FindAll(acct, i, 100);
            if (aList.Count() == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            _accounts.AddRange(aList);
        }
```

I guessed that my clients have no more than 300 accounts. Is there a way I can replace the 3 or use more efficient code?

Answer (score 1):

In QBO, paging is the only option to get all accounts.

In QBD, you can get the count using a rest api.PFB link.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_intuit_anywhere/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0100_calling_data_services/0015_retrieving_objects#Getting_a_Record_Count